# Bootstrap Modal on Safari 9.0.1 - Not Showing on window redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, safari

I'll try to keep this as short as possible.

I use Bootstrap 3 as a base for my project. On certain `<a>` tags I trigger a bootstrap modal with a loading message for the page. This works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox and even IE. In Safari though, as the page redirects, but the Boostrap modal never shows. Here are two samples of the code I use.

**The Tag Code**

```
<a href="urlgoeshere" class="event-link" data-name="event-name-goes-here">
```

**The Javascript that initiates the modal**

```
$('.event-link').click(function(){
    Controllers.UI.Modals.ShowLoaderModal('Loading '+$(this).data('name'));
});
```

**The Javascript that actually opens the Modal**

```
ShowLoaderModal: function(message) {
    var title = document.getElementById('loader-modal-title');
    title.innerHTML = message;
    $('#loader-modal').modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false
    });
}
```

I've done some searching but I couldn't find anything helpful. Should I change my approach or is there something I need to do for Safari as a workaround?

Comment: On a side note. 
If I incude the following:

    `$('.event-link').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // other code goes here
    });`

The modal actually shows up. Perhaps I should just redirect in the jQuery.

Comment: Ok, so redirecting in Javascript brings forth another issue. The loader shows, but as soon as the page redirect starts, the entire windows freezes until the new page is shown. Then, when pressing the back button, Safari then displays the previous page with the Bootstrap Modal still open...